# how to do a login attempt failed system

Tags: php, html, css

- I have the following loginsystem, following mmtuts on youtube and I
  am trying to add a login failed attempt system.
- If the user has logged in 5 times and failed, they can't login
  anymore for at least 10 mins but I found it hard to modify his code.
- . I have a feeling that it could be the line where he has if ($row =
  mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) {};
- Does this mean if $row exists? Shouldn't he done a num_row here?
  Whenever I tried to modify his code, the login.php page will just
  hang or freeze with a white border and no css displayed....

> ```
>  <?php
> if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) {
>    header("Location: ../index.php?login=error");
>    exit();
> } else {
>      include_once 'dbh.php';
>      include_once '../header2.php';
>      $uid =  $_POST['uid'];
>      $pwd =  $_POST['password'];
>
> date_default_timezone_set("Australia/Melbourne");
> $date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
> ```
>
> $sql = "UPDATE users SET user_session = ? 
>              WHERE user_uid = ?;";    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn) //Prepare the prepared statement    if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt,
>   $sql)) {
>        echo 'SQL statement failed';   } else {//Bind parameters to the placeholder   mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $date,
>   $_SESSION['u_uid']);  //Run parameters inside database 
>   mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);// include error handlers:
>             // Check to see if the inputs are empty
>            //Check to see if user has activated his or her account before logging in
>         $user_activate = 0;    if(empty($uid) || empty($pwd)) {
>               echo ""; 
>               exit();
>             } else {
>
> ```
>         // Check to see if user has activated his or her account
>
>         $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_activate = ? AND user_uid= ?;";
>
>        $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
>                             //Prepare the prepared statement
>        if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
>          echo 'SQL statement failed';
>        } else {
>        //Bind parameters to the placeholder
>       mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "is", $user_activate, $uid);
>       //Run parameters inside database
>       mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
>       $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
>       $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
>
>
>     if($resultCheck > 0) {
>       echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=../signup.php?signup=notactivated'>"; 
>        exit();
>        } else {
>
>
>         // Check to see if the username exists in the database
>
>         $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_uid = ? OR user_email = ?";
>         $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
>        //Prepare the prepared statement
>        if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
>           echo 'SQL statement failed';
>         } else {
>       //Bind parameters to the placeholder
>       mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $uid, $uid);
>       //Run parameters inside database
>       mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
>        $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
>        $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
>
>         if ($resultCheck < 1) {
>
>         echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=../index.php?login=notsignup'>";
>           exit();
>         } else {
>              // Does the password match the password in the database?
>        // while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result));
>           if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { // insert database results into an array
>             // De-hasing the password
>               $date = strip_tags(date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("+5 minutes")));
>       $login_attempts += 1;
>
>       $sql2 = "UPDATE users
>                SET login_attempts = ?, login_failed_delay = ?
>                WHERE user_uid = ?
>
>               ";
>
>       if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql2)) {
>           echo 'SQL statement failed';
>         } else {
>       //Bind parameters to the placeholder
>        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "iss", $login_attempts, $date, $uid);
>       //Run parameters inside database
>       mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
>             $hashedPwdCheck = password_verify($pwd, $row['user_password']);
>             if ($hashedPwdCheck == false && $date < $row['login_failed_delay']) {
>
>                echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=../login_attempt.php?login=passwordfailed&id=".$uid."''>";
>                 exit();
>             } elseif ($hashedPwdCheck == true && $date > $row['login_failed_delay']){
>                    // Log in the user here
>
>
>
>               $_SESSION['u_id'] = $row['user_id']; 
>               $_SESSION['u_first'] = $row['user_first'];   
>               $_SESSION['u_last'] = $row['user_last'];   
>               $_SESSION['u_email'] = $row['user_email'];
>               $_SESSION['u_uid'] = $row['user_uid'];  
>               $_SESSION['u_permission'] = $row['admin'];
>               $_SESSION['u_session'] = $row['user_session'];
>               $_SESSION['freelesson'] = $row['freelesson']; 
>               $_SESSION['datejoined'] = $row['datejoined'];
>               $_SESSION['premium'] = $row['premium'];
>
>               // Insert into reward points when login
>
>
>
>               // Select names from rewards
>
>               $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM rewards WHERE user_uid = ?;";
>
>               $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
>        //Prepare the prepared statement
>        if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql2)) {
>           echo 'SQL statement failed';
>         } else {
>       //Bind parameters to the placeholder
>       mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $uid);
>       //Run parameters inside database
>       mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
>        $result2 = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
>        $resultCheck2 = mysqli_num_rows($result2);
>
>        while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)) {
>
>
>
>               $_SESSION['u_reward_points'] = $row2['reward_points'];
>
>                $points = 100;
>               $_SESSION['u_reward_points'] += $points;
>
>
>               $sql = "UPDATE rewards
>                       SET reward_points = ?
>                       WHERE user_uid = ?;
>
>                      ";
>
>                $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
>        //Prepare the prepared statement
>        if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
>           echo 'SQL statement failed';
>         } else {
>       //Bind parameters to the placeholder
>       mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "is", $_SESSION['u_reward_points'], $_SESSION['u_uid']);
>       //Run parameters inside database
>       mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
>
>
>                 echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;URL=../header2.php?login=success' />" ;  
>                 exit();
>
>             }
>
>           }
>         }
>
>       }
>
> }
>
> }
> }
> }
> }
> }
> }
> }
> }
> ```

```
I get the following output on the screen:

[![enter image description here][1]]
```

Answer (score -1):

Create a global variable `$i = 0;`. Then for every login error (everytime you called `echo "SQL Statement Failed";`), do/add `$i++;`. And every time the form is submitted, call `stopLoginAttempts();`.

Remember, this is all client-side code. **Not Server-Side!**

```
function stopLoginAttempts() {
    if ($i == 5) {
        echo //echo a script tag that setTimeout(login, 5min);
    }
    elseif ($i == 10) {
        echo //echo a script tag with JS that will call another setTimeout that will stop login attempts for a certain amount of time
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but you are using function.... I am not familiar with function.. is there a way to do this without function?

Comment: and why do I get that weird looking login page?

Comment: @piano0011 Ok, no offense, but functions are VERY easy and they are the fundamentals of these types of languages.
Secondly, I'm not able to see all of the code in the Stack Overflow App, could you perhaps put the code in a codebin for me to see?

Comment: @piano0011 Also, functions is an easy way to do this, a work around would be difficult to conceive.

Comment: the website doesn't like it if I do this:

Comment: if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { // insert database results into an array
            // De-hasing the password
            
            $hashedPwdCheck = password_verify($pwd, $row['user_password']);
           
            if ($hashedPwdCheck == false && $row['login_attempts'] == 5) {

Comment: @piano0011 Why complicate it with row? Use the simple `$i`

Comment: Also, the `row` is used for items fetched from database. The 'login-attempts' variable is supposed to be client side, not server side.